# Typescript get type that excludes all functions from a class

Tags: typescript

I copy the data from a class instance using the spread operator: `const myObj:MyType = {...myClassInstance}`, where `myClassInstance` is an instance of `MyClass`. I want to define that type `MyType`, which *excludes all functions* defined on `MyClass`, keeping only strings, numbers, arrays etc. I tried this:

```
type ExcludeSubType<Base, Condition> = Pick<Base, {
  [Key in keyof Base]: Base[Key] extends Condition ? never : Key
}[keyof Base]>;

export type MyType = ExcludeSubType<MyClass, (_: any) => any>;
```

MyClass might look something like:

```
export class MyClass {
  foo: string;

  constructor(foo: string) {
    this.foo = foo;
  }

  stopTimer() {
    // stuff
  }

  startTimer() {
    // stuff
  }

  continue(p1: string, p2: number) {
    // stuff
  }

  setFailed(p1: string, p2: string) {
    // more stuff
  }
}
```

But `MyType` still has functions on it - in particular the functions with arguments. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could you share an example of `MyClass` definition? I think I understand what's wrong, but don't want to accidentally bark on a wrong tree.

Comment: The type appears to exclude functions.. are you looking for a runtime effect ? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=16&ssc=5&pln=14&pc=4#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcAmEDKKBGAVcCAHgCEBDAZwgBooBhAewDs0BLYV5gPigF4oACqwQBrUpRpQA3gCgoUANoBpCCCismUEaoYAzKOSoBdAFwGJy1UagQ4wCCwr1mbDsygB+KEwgA3CABOUGYqIDIAvgraIHrmxlwA3DLJyJROALIgdEhp0nLyUGQAFACUeQUVUPny4dVQOGalfDxStRVMZkwoALY4gREytmAMAcBQoJBQmQST-PDI6Fi4M8SZ2Wm0RQD6ZmRMIGW8PHsgiTIA9OfjhFMgK3x5l5Ud3j19AUlP4UA

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir I want it to exclude functions. It does not (well, not all of them).

Comment: @Cerberus - added, thanks.

Comment: @seesharper Did not have my coffee yet missed multi parameter . You need a `...` `export type MyType = ExcludeSubType<MyClass, (..._: any) => any>;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`export type MyType = ExcludeSubType<MyClass, Function>;`

The type `(_: any) => any` only matches functions that take at most one argument.

Answer (score 3):

Titian already has provided the answer, but I'd like to try and give some more verbose explanation.

The problem is that you're excluding only the very specific kind of function - the functions taking at most one argument, to be specific.

The `extends` relation can be understood as following: if `A extends B`, then `A` *is assignable* to `B`. In your case, it means that the excluded members must all be assignable to `(_: any) => any`, i.e. you can pass them somewhere where the functions of one argument are expected.

But, if your function takes *two* arguments (as does `setFailed` in your example), then you *can't* pass it into the place which will expect the function with one argument. Otherwise someone would be able to call your function without providing everything it is expecting. So, `(typeof setFailed) extends (_: any) => any` is false - this function will not be excluded, as you've already noted.

Then, how to do this? Obviously, you should exclude all functions, no matter how many arguments they have. It means that you need a type to which would be assignable every other function type. And we have two options for this, listed in other answers:

- You can simply use `Function` type from standard library. This will work, but this type may be banned by some linters as non-explicit.
- You can use an explicit typing. We need to express the fact that the (imaginary) function we're describing can take arbitrary large number of arguments. That's exactly the case when we can use [rest parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#rest-parameters), by "collecting" all the arguments into the tuple: `(...args: any[]) => any`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make `_` a rest parameter in order to match functions of any parameter arity:

```
export type MyType = ExcludeSubType<MyClass, (..._: any) => any>;
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=30&ssc=8&pln=30&pc=18#code/C4TwDgpgBAogHgYwDYFcAmEDKKBGAVcCAHgCEBDAZwgBooBhAewDs0BLYV5gPigF4oACqwQBrUpRpQA3gCgoUANoBpCCCismUEaoYAzKOSoBdAFwGJy1UagQ4wCCwr1mbDsygB+KEwgA3CABOUGYqIDIAvgraIHrmxlwA3DIytmAMAcBQyJROALIgdEg50nJQugwMZhTAARoA5kmlCMzVASgIwOkAFOWVUK31AJQl8vLAABasFAB0vXxlFUny4cny1QxgeKwAtoFdw7KjUAD0x-3AKLq6pSul1WQZW7sB+yOjp+eX18urWcwcTBQEC6YAAjFUavVaGAAExmQHbHCBA6leQfapfG6-KjAABiZFYSAgaBB4POtSYdWhcPJQzeaLO23S0AxVyxK1S6UyoEgUHyBF5-HgyHQWFwAuI+UKOVoXWm8oA+mYyEwQMNeDwVSBEjIPjzoPzCPNZB8jgs+gNKUkPuEgA)